# What Python libraries could I use to connect to a file on the internet and change it?

Tags: python, google-drive

I want to make a simple sort of messaging system. What I want is for Python to connect to a file on Google Drive, or an online file storage of the sort, and change it based on input, and then read the file and print it to the console. I assume that Python can't do this by itself, so I need a library recommendation. If anybody could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PyDrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/)

You need to [authenticate](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html#authentication-in-two-lines) and then [upload](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#upload-and-update-file-content) or [download](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#download-file-content) file content.